# How to match user drawing with predefined drawing model?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, firebase-mlkit, coremltools

I am trying to develop image recognition iOS app , i will have one reference image , and user has to draw something one screen and when user release finger , then i will convert his drawing into UIImage/CGImage, then i will be comparing the percentage of closeness to reference image .

If the percentage will be more then 90% then user will win . (See picture below , ignore  Red(user Canvas ) and  Yellow border(reference boundary will not include in atul image ) )

[image]

**What i have done till now** :

I created custom image array of each reference and then create MLModel from this website

https://cloud.ibm.com/developer/appledevelopment/starter-kits/custom-vision-model-for-core-ml-with-watson

This is my created model i have also run training on it :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pkunnq9AyXmPYkFdPVWtumXaxGzXm726

I tried to do this with the MLModel but every-time , app is showing 90+% percentage of , i am not able to do this .

**Please suggest**

I am trying to use MLKit in iOS Swift , i am doing wrong , if yes then what is the correct way to do this

Comment: Your drive url is protected i guess

Comment: Please check updated link .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow Apple template on how to use CoreML model with image, you will deal with CoreML and Vision frameworks.

[Classifying Images with Vision and Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml)